# vs code set custom color for class properties

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

In VS Code, settings.json file, I've changed many theme colors via **`workbench.colorCustomizations`** and **`editor.tokenColorCustomizations`** but can't find the key to use to change class property colors, if that is what you call them. In the example code below, I'm talking about the color of self.t_id_user.

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, t_id_user="", t_email="", t_password="", t_security_level="", t_name_first="", t_name_last="", t_enabled="", d_visit_first="", d_visit_last=""):
        self.t_id_user = t_id_user
        self.t_email = t_email
```

Help?

Comment: use command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope` to see if it has a unique scope identifier

Comment: Thank you! Where do I put the command?

Comment: Use the command to find the needed scope: `variable.other.readwrite` and `variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python`

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. Can you phrase that for a newb? WHERE do I type this "command"? Can you pretend I am not an expert with VS Code or - even better - that I've never even used it? Are you saying I go into settings.json and search? Or use the console in VS Code? Or do you mean pull up a command prompt in Windows? Are you sure you understand my goal is merely to change the color of how "self.t_id_user" appears in VS Code editor?

Comment: use `Ctrl_Shft+P` and search for the command, use the found scope rules in the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` `textMateRules` attribute

Answer (score 3):

You know settings way. That's why mine answer is:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {"textMateRules": [
    {
       "scope": ["storage.type"],
       "settings": {"foreground": "#080",}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
"textMateRules": [
    {
        "name": "Class access modifiers",
        "scope": [
            "storage.modifier",
        ],
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#CB4B16"
        }
    }
]}
```